# Find null values and duplicates between 3 sets of data, in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my database where our IT uploads computer names and the system they reside on. What we're currently doing is trying to reconcile which computer is missing from what system, and where duplicates reside.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    [item] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [system] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO test
(item, system)
VALUES
('item 1','system 1'),
('item 1','system 1'),
('item 1','system 2'),
('item 1','system 3'),
('item 2','system 2'),
('item 2','system 3'),
('item 3','system 1'),
('item 3','system 2');
```

I have provided a SQL Fiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/387a57/1/0) to as a sample data. My desired output would be [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1NyP.png).

[image]

Not really 100% where to start here.

EDIT: Updated question:

@MilenPavlov answered worked flawlessly for the sample data, however in a real world scenario, I won't know the names of the item. Only the systems are static. Is there a rendition of his query that doesn't use the name of the items?

EDIT: Found the solution, thanks everyone for the help!

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN system = 'system 1' THEN item END) system1
,MAX( CASE WHEN system = 'system 2' THEN item END) system2
,MAX( CASE WHEN system = 'system 3' THEN item END) system3
FROM test
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: Without a 3rd element for like a unique ID in the structure I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I couldn't post the image with my rep, and I was having issues formatting the SQL in the code block.

Comment: I could rewrite the script that uploads the initial data to the database, but what type of Unique ID would I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight deviation from your expected output but still take a look (using pivot):

```
select [system 1], [system 2], [system 3]
from
(
SELECT distinct system, item FROM test
  where item = 'item 1'
  ) x
pivot 
(
max(item)
  for system in ([system 1], [system 2], [system 3])
)p
union all
select [system 1], [system 2], [system 3]
from
(
SELECT distinct system, item FROM test
  where item = 'item 2'
  ) x
pivot 
(
max(item)
  for system in ([system 1], [system 2], [system 3])
)p
union all
select [system 1], [system 2], [system 3]
from
(
SELECT distinct system, item FROM test
  where item = 'item 3'
  ) x
pivot 
(
max(item)
  for system in ([system 1], [system 2], [system 3])
)p
```

demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/387a57/41

Comment: Wow, that's actually very impressive! That works exactly as expected. The only thing it's missing is locating duplicates.

However, duplicates would be easy to locate through a separate query.

Thanks @Milen Pavlov

Comment: @MilenPavlov, +1 that's a good one but is there any way we can achieve the same result without pivoting a table?

Comment: not quite sure to be honest, I was thinking that `pivot` is a good fit for the question...

Comment: @MilenPavlov, quick question, I was too impressed by that query to realize that I won't actually know what the name of the item is, so the WHERE condition in the query can't be there. Also, there will be much more than just 3 different items in the database.

Is there a way to adjust this query?

Answer (score 0):

```
   select 
   case  when system='system 1' then item
   END ,
   case when system='system 2' then item 
   END ,
   case when system='system 3' then item
   END 
   FROM TEST;
```

Comment: That doesn't give the desired result. It only ever gives one value in a row plus two nulls.

Comment: Hey @VJMaestro, thank you for your post, you actually helped us find the solution!